# How to calculate margin of error for a survey question?

Tags: confidence-interval, survey, error, multinomial-distribution

I am working on a perception survey of a nationally-representative sample ($n=1243$). I want to calculate the margin of error for each question. A typical question is coded like this:

```
1. very good
2. good
3. bad
4. very bad
98. refused (vol.)
99. don't know (vol.)
```

I believe I know how to calculate the margin of error for a dichotomous variable: $MoE=z\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$. But I mostly have 4 options.

Comment: This may sound like splitting hairs, but I think you want margins of error not for "each question" but for the % of respondents who choose each option.  Right?  Another approach would be to obtain a m.o.e. for the mean response on a scale from 1 to 4, something that, because of its simplicity, would probably appeal to a lot of readers.

Comment: You are right, I meant to say margins of error for % of respondents who choose each option of a question. Can you please elaborate more on obtaining moe for mean of a scale?

Answer (score 1):

Often newpapers will present polls "yes/no", like/dislike, success/failure type polls with a margin of error of 3%. A version of this calculation, similar to the one you mention, as presented on page 92 of Schaeffer, Mendehall, and Ott's *Elementary Survey Sampling text* (6E) is

> $2 \sqrt{\hat{V}(\hat{p})} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\hat{q}}{n - 1} \frac{N - n}{N}}$

where  $\hat{q} = 1 - \hat{p}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{N - n}{N}}$ is the, often ignored, finite population correction.

Now, these papers will poll roughly 1,000 respondents and (ignoring the finite population correction) this calculation returns roughly 0.032 at its maximum which is when $\hat{p} = \hat{q} = 0.5$.

To calculate a margin of error in the presence of multiple categories, consider a single category as the "success" and combine the remaining categories. Then, as mentioned in the comment by @rolando2, the above margin of error would put a bound on the proportion of respondents who chose that category.

Note that the identical formulas are also grounded in the identical variances of the closely related binomial and multinomial distributions which are both $n \hat{p}_i (1- \hat{p}_i)$.

*links to mathworld*
[multinomial distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialDistribution.html)
[binomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. As your suggestion, I can calculate moe for one category of respondents (success category/rest). This way I can calculate moe for each category of respondents. So if I have four categories, I will have four moe. Do you think an average of the four moe yields the overall moe for that question? Does that make sense?

Comment: The conservative approach is to assume 50% in category, 50% rest. This maximizes the MOE and, subsequently makes the MOE the same for each category.

Comment: How about if I know that each of four categories have for instance 30%, 20%, 40% and 10%? I was asking if I can calculate moe for each category, and then take their average to calculate the question's moe. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'd recommend the conservative route that I outlined.